# User can multiple?

Tags: php, yii2

Я использую `Yii::$app->user->can` для проверки доступности для конкретной роли, но как быть если доступ должен быть у нескольких ролей? Например у юзера и редактора. Писать `Yii::$app->user->can('user') && Yii::$app->user->can('editor')` не торт. Нет ли там какой-то возможности одной функцией проверить несколько ролей? В доках я этого не нашел, но вдруг я пропустил что-то... Очень этого не хватает.

P.S. Про то что можно редактору юзера добавить как дочерний элемент знаю, но так не буду делать потому что есть вещи которые редактор наоборот видеть не должен, а юзер должен.

Comment: Насколько помню, нет такой возможности

Comment: Для всех общих операций, которые доступны нескольким ролям, добавьте отдельный permission и присвойте его нужным ролям. Потом просто `Yii::$app->user->can('commonPermission')` и всё, не надо для каждой операции отдельное название писать.

Answer (score 0):

Если исходить из RBAC, то лучше тогда проверять не роль, а доступность операции конкретному пользователю. Т.е. каждая роль будет иметь свой набор
доступных действий. 
Хорошая статья, правда про yii 1.0 - https://habrahabr.ru/post/177873/

Comment: Мне кажется слишком геморно писать для каждой операции название. Это же надо еще каждый раз лезть в БД, добавлять там нужное название (которое еще надо придумать) и все ради того чтобы показать или скрыть одну кнопочку. Намного проще и быстрее проверять роль.

Comment: Названия операций да, придется придумать. А вот в базе ничего менять не нужно. У пользователей так и останутся роли, только нужно сделать привязку к роли набора доступных ей операций.

Comment: У меня роли и все остальное в базе хранится.

Comment: Ну, это уже дело вкуса. Иногда некоторая избыточность - плата за гибкость :) Я у себя обычно организовывал через отдельный конфиг, где были заданы роли и их чайлды. Меняется это не часто, и в базу лезть не нужно каждый раз.